# Filling a hidden field in a html form through javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to send someone an email through a form on my website. I want to include a part of my webpage into the email.

To do this I use a hidden field, which I try to fill using a piece of javascript. However due to my lack of knowledge the code doesn't seem to be triggered.

```
<form action="Emailverstuurd.php" method="POST">
<input id="ExcelForm" type="hidden" name="ExcelForm"/>
<input name="email">
<textarea name="body" rows="10" cols="60"> </textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#send").submit(function() {
    $("#ExcelForm").val($("#myExcelDiv").html());
}
</script>
<input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="Send Your Message"/>
</p>
</form>
```

How can I get my javascript code to run?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<form action="Emailverstuurd.php" method="POST" onsubmit="submitUpdate()">
<input id="ExcelForm" type="hidden" name="ExcelForm"/>
<input name="email">
<textarea name="body" rows="10" cols="60"> </textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitUpdate()
    {
        $("#ExcelForm").val($("#myExcelDiv").html());
    }
</script>
<input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="Send Your Message"/>
</p>
</form>
```

Just add an onsubmit handler to your `form` field give it a function and just put you `value` update in that function...I don't see `#myExcelDiv` I'm assuming that is defined somewhere else in your code?